# How to use * in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am wondering how I can strategically use the `*` in Stata to make my do-file cleaner.

I'd like to replace values of `999` with missing `(.)` for a long list of variables, one for each year.

Here is my existing code:

```
replace age_1997 = . if age_1997 == 999
replace age_1998 = . if age_1998 == 999
replace age_1999 = . if age_1999 == 999
```

Is there some way to do this more efficiently? I have tried the following, but it did not work.

```
replace age* = . if age* == 999
```

Comment: A different issue is that you have a wide layout, with information on different times held within single observations. Many Stata operations are easier with a long layout.

Comment: Great point, thanks for your observation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special-purpose command for this problem

```
mvdecode age*, mv(999)
```

which isn't necessarily faster than a loop:

```
foreach v of var age* { 
    replace `v' = . if `v' == 999 
}
```

Note that `help replace` is explicit: the command only works on one variable at a time.

Comment: Thanks so much! The `mvdecode` command is exactly what I need!